# Template and Forward declaration in Apple LLVM 3.0

Tags: xcode, gcc, llvm-gcc, llvm-clang

I am working on an application(contains 3 projects, 2 in c++ and one in Objective-C) which compiles perfectly for LLVM GCC compiler. But when I switch the compiler to 'Apple LLVM compiler 3.0' I found one strange error as follow:

```
error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'EList<ETemplateString<char>>'
```

and above error shows in the following line of code:

```
   EList<EString> outlist;
```

with the forward declared EList as follows:

```
template <class T> class EList; // forward decls
```

EString is declared as follow:

```
typedef ETemplateString<TCHAR>         EString;
```

and rest of the used templates are defined as:

```
template <class T> class ETemplateString
{
//
//
//
}
```

and TCHAR is declared as:

```
typedef char TCHAR;
```

can anybody please let me know why it's compiling good with GCC and throwing errors in 'Apple LLVM compiler 3.0'

Answer (score 1):

See http://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html#undep_incomplete .